# github desktop installation windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, github-for-windows

I am trying to install github desktop on windows 8 64 bit OS. running GitHubSetup.exe fails. I tried running it in compatibility mode, but that fails too. Turning off UAC didn't work either. :-(

**Has anyone got similar issue and got github desktop running on windows 8?**

The error dialog box of installer comes up and says 'Application can't be started. Contact the application vendor.'.
And this is the 'Details...' button of installer shows...

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.96.0 built by: NETFXREL2STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.81.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                        Server      : AmazonS3
    Application url         : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_3_0_6_4/GitHub.exe.manifest
                        Server      : AmazonS3

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=3.0.6.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Specified cast is not valid.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [13-10-2015 11:43:54] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
    * [13-10-2015 11:43:55] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [13-10-2015 11:43:55] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [13-10-2015 11:43:57] System.InvalidCastException
        - Specified cast is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 2):

[New Edit]

So after checking a few things, I could not figure out what was wrong. But Github Desktop has recently (29 October 2015) come out with a new version (v3.0.7, "Never Gonna Git You Up") that seems to have fixed the problem.

So in short, try installing the new version. It should work now.

https://desktop.github.com

[/New Edit]

I have had the Github desktop client up and running properly on windows 8 for several months now. So it **should** work.

BUT as of this morning (10 mins ago), my client won't run. The last time I ran it was on Friday. My error looks very similar to yours. I have tried redownloading the installer and reinstalling it, but an error still happens.

Maybe it is a new Windows update that broke it, I don't know. But your problem is not exclusive to you ;). If I figure it out I will update.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/tcowley0/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start%20Menu/Programs/GitHub,%20Inc/GitHub.appref-ms%7C

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\tcowley0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc\GitHub.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [10/13/2015 8:32:57 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\tcowley0\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc\GitHub.appref-ms| has started.
    * [10/13/2015 8:32:57 AM] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [10/13/2015 8:32:57 AM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: this is not an answer